# Resolve DNS in LAN using router/server configuration

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, lan

I'm trying to setup an internal test server with a domain name so that I can test my application. I have a D-Link WiFi router and a server machine running 
Ubuntu buster. The Server is connected to the WiFi router through an Ethernet cable. Here's what I did so far:

1. Assigned static IP to my server as 192.168.x.x
2. Declared 192.168.x.x as test.app in /etc/hosts file on the server
3. Created a Virtual Host entry in Apache on the Server to handle all requests from test.app

Based on the above configuration, when I open a browser in the server and type "test.app", it takes me to my application home page. This is working fine.

When I connect another machine to the WiFi network, I'm able to ping the server's IP address 192.168.x.x directly. But when I enter "test.app" I'm not able to get any response.

I have enabled port forwarding on the router for ports 80 and 53 using tcp and udp protocols. I have also opened firewalls for the ports on my server machine.

What should be my next step so that "test.app" from my client machine can access my application on the server?

Please note that there is no internet connection anywhere in the network. This is completely working on LAN configuration. I can only access the server machine and change the router configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added test.app to the hosts file on the 2nd machine (and any others) you are connecting? As there's no DNS operating here (that I can see) you will need to set it manually on all client machines

Comment: I cannot do that. Some of the client machines are tablets and mobile devices and I don't know how to change the hosts file in those devices.

Comment: Set up a DNS server on the "server machine" (and optionally make the DHCP server on the router give out the machine's IP as the DNS server IP).

Comment: Simplest way should be to simply add a static IP entry on the router for "test app".  There's a caveat if the connected WiFi device is running Windows, as you'll likely not only have to add "test app" to the Windows host file, you'll [likely] need to configure all the devices (server, router, and Windows) to be on the same local domain name (on Windows, this is the WorkGroup name)

Comment: I have installed a DNS Server on my server machine using this tutorial: https://www.ostechnix.com/install-and-configure-dns-server-ubuntu-16-04-lts/ . I have configured my router to serve my server IP as DNS IP. I then assigned test.app as domain name in router's DHCP configuration. I restarted my server and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot @tom-yan 

However, the app is very slow on the client machine. I will keep working on it.

Comment: BTW, bind9 is overkill for that, dnsmasq is completely sufficient (and will use the entries in /etc/host). But if it already works, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm converting the comments to an answer. The solution is based on @tom-yan's comment.

1. Install a DNS server on the server machine. I followed this tutorial: ostechnix.com/install-and-configure-dns-server-ubuntu-16-04-lts
2. Change the router DHCP configuration to provide the domain name as "test.app" and DNS IP as 192.168.x.x (server IP)
3. Restart the server.

This should solve the issue.